# Reduce HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, httpwebrequest

I'm using this code to dynamically load external pages

```
$(function() {
   $('#nav a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(page + '.php');
    return false;
    });
});
```

I've noticed that each time I click on one of the menu tabs, a new HTTP request is sent and the page is loaded again. I'm wondering how to make each page load once so when I go through the tabs, the pages that have been already loaded display without sending new requets ?

Comment: After the first load, the pages should be cached making the HTTP request/response a trivial Not Modified response. Is this not the case?

Comment: It's probably not the case because his pages probably don't report themselves as cacheable because they're dynamically generated. You can control the cacheability by adjusting the PHP code to output the appropriate hearers.

Comment: I think jQuery adds an anti cache GET parameter to Ajax requests.

Comment: I don't think so, when I go to "Network" tab in the Chrome Developer Tools, each time I click on Info tab in my website I see a new line requesting info.php

Comment: @WolfgangStengel ahhh interesting. I learned something today. Makes sense why jQuery would do that with AJAX, but it was not something I was aware was default behavior. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you need to call event.preventDefault() at the beginning of your click handler.

Comment: @WolfgangStengel They do that with getScript.

Answer (score 3):

You could "tag" tabs that are already loaded with a flag using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and only issue the HTTP request when the tag is non-existent.

**Edit**: Regarding Kryptonite's comment this would be a simple approach to the problem:

```
var pages = {};

$(function() {
  $('#nav a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');

    if (!(page in pages)) {
      $.get(page, function (data) {
        pages[page] = data;
      });
    }

    $('#content').html(pages[page]);

    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks like he has one display pane which is rebuilt each time a new tab is clicked. I could be wrong, but wouldn't he have to store the page content as well for each page?

Comment: Yes, so he could adapt this approach to store the contents in an object and load the content, when the object does not have such a key.

Comment: I suppose so, but that is effectively writing his own cache engine. There must be a standard way to do it.

Comment: I edited in a simple approach regarding your comment. The technically best approach would be to give the loaded pages an appropriate Cache-Control/Expires header and leave the JS code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('loaded') !== true) {
        // Load it.
        $this.data('loaded', true);
    } else {
        alert('Already loaded that one!');
    }
});
```

This will do what you need.  You'll need to throw your load code in where I have the `// Load it.` comment, and might want to remove the `else` block as well.  http://jsfiddle.net/rRumK/